# Would there be any SEO implications, if I had a URL, which did not fully reflect a page's Directory Path?

Tags: seo, url

**URL example:**

```
www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/daffodil-canvas-prints
```

Let's say I am looking to implement the above Product Category URL.  It is fairly clear that the page would be about 'Floral Canvas Prints'.

One of the obvious issues here, is the duplicate use of 'canvas-prints', within the 2 directories.  Firstly, is this actually an issue?  If so, what kind of issue would this be?  Does it really affect SEO, from a technical stand point, or is it more of an indirect issue.  For example, duplicate words, extends a URL and increases the chances of people forgetting the URL; to return to the site in the future?

I know I could use variations, such as:

```
www.example.com/floral/daffodil-canvas-prints
```

or

```
www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/daffodils
```

My issue here, is that whilst these variants convey what each page is, the context becomes lost as soon as you look at each directory in isolation.

This brings me to my own approach.  Is there anything wrong with simply scrapping multiple directories, within the URL altogether, and focusing on longer descriptive directory names?

For example:

```
www.example.com/wall-art/floral-canvas-prints/daffodil-canvas-prints
```

… would simply be:

```
www.example.com/daffodil-canvas-prints
```

Despite having this shortened URL, the on page Breadcrumbs would still have the following path shown:

> Wall Art > Floral Canvas Prints > Daffodil Canvas Prints

My only concern would be, that the page's  attempt at targeting Keywords, such as `Daffodil Canvas Wall Art`, may be impacted.  A small impact, maybe, but an impact nonetheless.  Would I be right?

I realise that the URL is a small factor, within the grand scheme of things, but I would like to atleast try and 'tick all the boxes' as I work from the ground up.

Comment: "the context becomes lost as soon as you look at each directory in isolation." - Although you never do look at each in isolation. The URL is a single entity. Either `/foo`, `/foo/bar` or `/foo/bar/baz`. Never just `bar` or `baz`.

Comment: @DocRoot:  Thanks for your guidance.  Understand the URL structure more now.  I guess the URL does (well, should) mirror the internal linking structure.  As such, the internal linking structure 'passes' a little bit of context along with each link to and fro, between 'Parent and Child' Directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last name in a URI should be the subject of the URL. URIs are mainly for machine use, not humans, but humans deal with URIs and you should make them as logical as possible.

So, the end subject is "floral canvas prints" and, this case, "Daffodil" so you should go in that order and not use redundant wording. `floral-canvas-prints -> daffodils`. We already know they are floral canvas prints.

You have more than one sub category of floral canvas prints so reserve those words for the parent.

A different example of what you are thinking of doing: you wouldn't do `humans/male-human/rob-human` would you?

Comment: I especially appreciate your point of not repeating terms in url segments (/). On one hand, each segment is taken separately while on the other hand, all are taken together for a complete understanding. Cheers!!

Comment: @Rob:  Thanks for your answer.  I see what you mean.  Maybe I am adopting an over optimising approach, of maintaining context for each directory level etc.  What about product variants?  For example `/white-roses/`.  Would `/white-roses/` be considered a subject at the same directory level as `/roses/` or would this be considered a Child of `/roses/`, since the visitor would be drilling down into the product, so to speak?

Comment: @closetnoc:  I guess internal linking (as well as backlinks etc) may help provide any outstanding context, which the URL fails to?!

Comment: @Craig Yes. Drilling down that way is how you want to do categorization. `roses/white` and `roses/red`, etc.

Comment: @Craig Yes! Bingo!!

Comment: @Craig It is all a balancing act. The content is paramount of course, but the little stuff matters too. You really do not have to sweat it too much since one thing can easily make up for another. You get that now! Cheers!! See? You are becoming an expert!

Comment: @Rob:  Thanks for the confirmation.  Keeping with the example of `/roses/white`, it does not come without issues.  When dealing with CMS anyway.  The `/white` slug can only be assigned, as a Child Category, once.  If an attempt is made, to assign to additional Parent Categories, it becomes prefixed with the parent Category.  `/roses/white` becoming `/roses/roses-white`.  I know I can modify 'roses-white' to 'white-roses' but it does leave the issue of the duplicate use of 'roses'.  Would this be an example of where duplicate references are acceptable or should the practice of synonyms be ...

Comment: ... used here?  For example, `/roses/red` becoming `/roses/red-flowers`, `/roses/red-rosette` etc?

Comment: Reason #9178 why my company will never, EVER use someone else's CMS.

Comment: @Rob:  Building a CMS, from scratch, is not an option at present.  Are you saying that the inability to have duplicate directory folder names, such as `.../roses/white` and `.../lilies/white`, should be something I should consider?  Is it really, that much of an issue?